# How can I cause ldap_simple_bind_s to timeout?

Tags: c, linux, unix, ldap

We recently had a problem with our test LDAP server - it was hung and wouldn't respond to requests. As a result, our application hung forever* while trying to bind to it. This only happened on Unix machines - on Windows, the `ldap_simple_bind_s` call timed out after about 30 seconds.

* I don't know if it really was *forever*, but it was at least several minutes.

I added calls to `ldap_set_option`, trying both `LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT` and `LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT`, but the bind call still hung. Is there any way to make `ldap_simple_bind_s` time out after some period of time of my choosing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things happening here.

Basically the LDAP SDK is broken; based on the spec it should have timed out based upon the value you sent in ldap_set_option. Unfortunately it's not doing that properly. Your bind will probably eventually time out, but it won't be until the OS returns back a failure, and that will come from the TCP timeout or some multiple of that timeout.

You can work around this by using ldap_simple_bind(), then calling ldap_result() a couple of times. If you don't get the result back within the timeout you want you can call ldap_abandon_ext() to tell the SDK to give up.

Of course since you're trying to bind this will almost certainly leave the connection in an unusable state and so you will need to unbind it immediately.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I don't know why using the asynchronous version of the function didn't occur to me but that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: below code is only working on openldap 2.4+. openLdap 2.3 does not honor LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT without which ldap_simple_bind_s will not timeout regardless of what you set. Here is the [link](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/200804/msg00125.html) from openLdap forum

I am using ldap_simple_bind_s in my LDAP auth service, and with setting LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT, LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT, and LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT; it successfully times out if the LDAP server is unavailable.

Here is the code excerpt from my LDAP Connect Method:

```
  int opt_timeout     = 4;               // LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT
  int timelimit       = 4;               // LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT
  int network_timeout = 4;               // LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT
  int status = 0;

      // Set LDAP operation timeout(synchronous operations)

      if ( opt_timeout > 0 )
      {

          struct timeval optTimeout;
          optTimeout.tv_usec = 0;
          optTimeout.tv_sec = opt_timeout;

          status = ldap_set_option(connection, LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT, (void *)&optTimeout);
          if ( status != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS )
          {
              return false;
          }
      }

      // Set LDAP operation timeout
      if ( timelimit > 0 )
      {
          status = ldap_set_option(connection, LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT, (void *)&timelimit);
          if ( status != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS )
          {
              return false;
          }
      }

      // Set LDAP network operation timeout(connection attempt)
      if ( network_timeout > 0 )
      {
          struct timeval networkTimeout;
          networkTimeout.tv_usec = 0;
          networkTimeout.tv_sec = network_timeout;

          status = ldap_set_option(connection, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, (void *)&networkTimeout);
          if ( status != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS )
          {
              return false;
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify option LDAP_OPT_TCP_USER_TIMEOUT - if this option available in your Ldap SDK. For OpenLdap and Linux it works nice - if no TCP answer will get in this timeout, synchronous operation is terminated.

See [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ldap_get_option.3.html)