# OpenLDAP Bind Timeout

Tags: c, linux, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to understand how to properly implement a timeout for an OpenLDAP bind request to an LDAP server. From what I've found, there seems to be two ways to do this, with LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT and LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT. My main confusion comes from trying to figure out what the difference is between these.

So far as I understand it, TIMELIMIT is an LDAP standard that sets the time limit for the request/response cycle for any ldap search. And in Windows at least, the default is 120 seconds.

On the other hand TIMEOUT is OpenLDAP specific and used purely client-side for timing out LDAP bind requests. This actually sounds closest to what I want to implement. I know from discussions that using an ldap_set_opt for TIMEOUT was not fully implemented until 2.4. From [How can I cause ldap_simple_bind_s to timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842661/how-can-i-cause-ldap-simple-bind-s-to-timeout) I know that the work around for earlier versions is to use an asynchronous bind, followed by an ldap_result with the timeout and an ldap_abandon_ext in the case of timeout to drop the request. That makes sense, though looking through the source code for synchronous bind in version 2.4, it doesn't ever seem to handle a timeout in this way. This makes me wonder what the importance of calling ldap_abandon_ext is.

Any answers or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: A bind is not a search so TIMELIMIT is not relevant.

Comment: That's where it seems to be a bit confusing. [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seem to suggest that TIMELIMIT applies to both binds and searches, which [OpenLDAP](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_set_option) seems to separate them with TIMEOUT and TIMELIMIT. Is this just a difference in implementation?

Comment: Different APIs. These things aren't part of the LDAP specifications.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for OpenLDAP bind timeout yet, you should use method from Aki's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139413/3929506). 
It is also working in ldapcpp library, when using LDAPAsynConnection for bind. Before bind you must just enable it using getSessionHandle() method.